# What bucket permissions are required to download zip file directly from URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am following a tutorial [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial3_Basic_QA_Pipeline_without_Elasticsearch.ipynb#scrollTo=7zSSd7hHz2TZ) and if I take this s3 URL from the tutorial, `https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/deepset.ai-farm-qa/datasets/documents/wiki_gameofthrones_txt.zip`, I am able to directly download the zip file to local.

When I subsistute my own zip file URL, I get an error that `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`, and if I try my URL for zip file, I get permission denied instead of being able to download.

I also confirmed the zip files are formated correctly using terminal: `unzip -t zipfile.zip`

What permissions do I need to change in s3 or on the s3 object to allow download of zip file directly from URL?

Still very new to IAM s3 permissions and current permission are the standard ones when creating bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**. This means that they cannot be accessed by an anonymous URL (like you have shown).

If you want a specific object to be **publicly available** (meaning that anyone with the URL can access it), then use the **Make Public** option in the S3 management console. This can also be configured at the time that the object is uploaded by specifying `ACL=public-read`.

If you want a whole bucket, or particular paths *within* a bucket, to be public, then you can create a **Bucket Policy** that grants access to the bucket. This requires **S3 Block Public Access** to be disabled.

You can also generate n [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to a private object. The pre-signed URL has additional information added that grants permission to access the private object. This is how web applications provide access to private objects to authorized users, such as photo websites.

If an object is accessed via an AWS API call or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), then AWS credentials are used to identify the user. If the user has permission to access the object, then they can download it. This method uses an API call rather than a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- Make your bucket/file public. Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html) ( Not recommended)

  ```
  {
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
      {
        "Sid":"PublicRead",
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
        "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"]
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- Use pre-signed URLs with SDK .. check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html)

  ```
  var params = {Bucket: bucketname , Key: keyfile , Expires: 3600 , ResponseContentDisposition :  `attachment; filename="filename.ext"` };

  var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
  ```